# .Net Tool or Library to compare one PDF to another PDF

Tags: vb.net, pdf, compare

I am working on a project that currently uses a .tiff, compares the defined template document to the document in question.  We are moving away from the .tiff format for a variety of reasons but mainly because the new files will be coming in the format of PDF.

I see two potential solutions to the issue.  First convert the PDF to a tiff and use the existing code.

Or second, use a PDF library that will compare the template PDF to the PDF that is received.

Because the PDF that is received will basically come from an outside source we won’t know for sure if it is text based or image based so the library or tool will have to be able to compare both.

Any suggestions on tools/libraries you have found helpful would be great!

Thank you in advance!

dj

Comment: You want *visual* comparison of 2 PDFs, not *structural*, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What we ended up doing was using the [`Aspose.Pdf`](http://www.aspose.com/) library.

I ended up learning there are two types of PDFs:

- Image based and
- Text based

I did not have any issues comparing the Text based PDFs. However, at the point that a image based PDF was received converting the PDF to a `.tiff` so that we could use Microsoft's MODI to compare the PDF against our specified template.  The `.tiff` would be a blank image rather than the actual content of the PDF.  Aspose.Pdf library did cost some money, however in the end, the library did exactly what we needed it to and it allowed us to meet our client's needs.

Answer (score 2):

How about [i-net PDFC](http://www.inetsoftware.de/other-products/pdf-content-comparer) - it does a full content comparison - text, images, lines, header/footer-detection and so on. You can use it either on command line or with a GUI (2.0, currently in public beta-phase) or via API (I think we have an internal version being a .NET library).

Disclaimer: Yep, I work for the company who made this - so feedback highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think your method of comparing tiffs is the way to go, using ImageMagick or other library?
Converting PDF to images can also be done via ImageMagick with the help of Ghostscript.

http://www.imagemagick.org/script/compare.php

I have a C# wrapper for GhostScript that may help, sent me a mail (on profile) and I can send it to you.

Comment: Thank you Mark for your reply!

Answer (score 0):

[Docotic.Pdf library](https://bitmiracle.com/pdf-library/) can compare PDF documents for you.

Please have a look at [Check that two PDF documents are equal](https://github.com/BitMiracle/Docotic.Pdf.Samples/tree/master/Samples/General%20operations/CompareDocuments) sample.

We use this feature for regression testing of the library itself (yes, I am part of the library's dev team).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see from your question, you want *visual* comparison of 2 PDFs, not *structural* comparison. (Because I can create you a thousand different PDF pages, which will have different internal structures and PDF source code, but will render identically on screen or on paper.)

In this case *any* comparison software will have to transform the 2 PDFs into raster images and compare those.

But since you have your own code already to do that for TIFFs, you can as well re-use it for PDFs (like you are considering already) which you convert to TIFFs.

*Unless you find another, external tool that is better, faster, more precise, more funky, less resource-hungry... than your own solution!* -- But that one will not be able to avoid converting the PDF pages to some sort of raster image before it can start the real visual comparison. (This may happen internally and unnoticeable for the user, but nevertheless it will have to take place...)